# Couchbase server refusing network connections - any ideas what might be the issue?

Tags: macos, couchdb, couchbase

I downloaded the community edition of couchbase server, and am running it on a mac system.

It's up and running according to the console:

[image]

However, when I try to test it:

```
$ telnet localhost 8091
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I've told the firewall app to allow the "Couchbase Server.app" application to accept incoming network connections, and doesn't seem to have helped.

Any ideas what might be the issue here?

Comment: I've also tried disabling my firewall altogether, and telnet-ing in, to check if that might be the problem, but it didn't really make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, telnet into Couchbase should be through 11211... http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-1.8/couchbase-getting-started-testing.html

Did you try to connect to it through any of the SDK's (C/Ruby/Java/.NET/PHP/Python/Perl)? If you ever need immediate help, you can also go to IRC (freenode.net), in the #libcouchbase or #couchbase channels, or post another question here of course.

Answer (score 0):

I was connecting to the server on the wrong port. To see the port to use when accessing the server, open up the relevant data bucket, and check what port it's running on. By default, it will most likely be accessible on 11211